# Pros & Cons of MSMQ vs AKKA?

Tags: akka, msmq, distributed-computing, akka.net

I'm couple of steps down the road to use MSMQ in my attempts to 'decouple' and a-synchronize processes withing huge systems with multiple modules and entities. I was recently told that I should consider AKKA.net framework and I've start looking into it. Now I'm bit on the fence not being sure about how to proceed.
I'm more familiar with MSMQ and in my mind implementation would be easier with less code required. I would just generate proper messages in the DAL (data access layer) and interested parties (handlers) would pick them up. 
Am I comparing apples & oranges? Any tip would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I comparing apples & oranges?

I think you're comparing apples to an orange juice factory.

MSMQ is a point-to-point, store-and-forward Windows messaging subsystem.

AKKA is an [OTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Telecom_Platform)-style design-time framework and run-time platform.